# How to convert string to float in Python? Why is it a float when directly assigned but a string when a user inputs it?

Tags: python, string, math

My program prompts the user to input the volume of a sphere. This is one of the example input I have to try:

- 1.4*1.0e6

This is what I have as the prompt right now: `volume = float(input("Enter volume of sphere in mm^3: "))`

And I got this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.4*1.0e6'`

Why is it that when I directly assign the value of a variable like `a = 1.4*1.0e6`, it's a float but when the user inputs, it's a string? How do I convert it to float? Is there any built-in functions to do that?

Sorry for my bad English and thank you.

Comment: Please check these answers to ["How do I parse a string to a float or int?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379906/2314737): https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929983/2314737 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17815252/2314737

Comment: `1.4 * 1.0e6` is not directly a float: it's a multiplication of two floats. When you write it in code, the multiplication is evaluated, and the result is a float. But if you call `float('1.4 * 1.0e6')`, you will get an error, because `float( )` can converts strings into floats, not convert strings into multiplications then perform the multiplication. Note that `1.4 * 1.0e6` will evaluate to the same number as `1.4e6`; and `float('1.4e6')` will work as you want it to. So, just tell your user to enter the expression of a float directly, rather than a multiplication of two floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting a string to float you can use float().
Eg.float('1.2123')
You can not convert '*' into float because its an operator that's why error is coming.

```
#observe the code
volume = float(input("Enter volume of sphere in mm^3: "))
```

input() = Takes input from user and stores it in string

float() = It is used to convert strings to float

Your code is volume = float(**input("Enter volume of sphere in mm^3: ")**)

1st input() takes input from user in string then float() converts it into float.

But **a = 1.4*1.0e6** there is no input() function involved thats why it's a float.

You can simply achieve your work by

```
volume = eval(input("Enter volume of sphere in mm^3: "))
```

OR

```
volume = input("Enter volume of sphere in mm^3: ").split("*")
volume = float(volume[0])*float(volume[1])
```

split(separator)- It splits a string into an array of sub-strings, by a separator string provided by user

You can read about eval from here:-
[Read abut eval() from here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)

Answer (score -1):

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.4*1.0e6'`
you try to convert formula to float. the most easy way is convert string to formula using `eval`

`volume = eval(input("Enter volume of sphere in mm^3: "))`

Comment: suggesting `eval` without warning... cringe... :-P

Answer (score -1):

```
s = '10.5674'
f = float(s)
print(type(f))
print('Float Value =', f)
```

Output:

```
<class 'float'>
Float Value = 10.5674.
```

This way you can convert string to float. Also, in your case you write `*` between numbers so it can't convert in proper way. You have to assign float number in different variables then perform an operation.